# "Programming Pearls": Sampling m elements from a sequence

Tags: algorithm, sampling

From *Programming Pearls*: [Column 12: A Sample Problem](http://books.google.com/books?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&lpg=PA132&ots=DgvTzPwR8x&dq=programing%20pearls%20column%2012&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The input consists of two integers *m* and *n*, with *m* < *n*. The output is
>   a sorted list of *m* random integers in the range *0..n-1* in which no
>   integer occurs more than once. For probability buffs, we desire a
>   sorted selection without replacement in which each selection occurs
>   with equal probability.

The author provides one solution:

```
initialize set S to empty
size = 0
while size < m do
    t = bigrand() % n
    if t is not in S
        insert t into S
        size++
print the elements of S in sorted order
```

In the above pseudocode, `bigrand()` is a function returns a large random integer (much larger than *m* and *n*).

Can anyone help me prove the correctness of the above algorithm?

According to my understanding, every output should have the probability of 1/C(*n*, *m*).
How to prove the above algorithm can guarantee the output with the probability of 1/C(*n*, *m*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each solution this algorithm yields is valid.

How many solutions are there?
Up to last line there (sorting) are `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*..*(n-m)` different permutations or
`n!/(n-m)!` and each result has same probability

When you sort you reduce number of possible solutions by m!.

So number of possible outputs is `n!/((n-m)!*m!)` and this is what you asked for.

`n!/((n-m)!m!)  = C(n,m)`